# Could flash media player play wmv/asf format media?

Tags: flash, wmv, asf

I have tried to play wmv/asf file in HTML page, but always Windows Media Player is embedded in browser, but Flash Media Player is not embedded.

Here is my code to embed Flash Media Player. I suspect it is because Flash Media player does not support wmv/asf format, so even if I explicitly assign "application/x-shockwave-flash" value, Flash Media player is not displayed. Any ideas?

Does Flash Media player support wmv/asf file?

```
<html>
<body>
<embed src="http://myserver/videos/123.asf" quality="high" width="480" height="400" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There's an obvious confusion here : ***Flash Player*** is not directly a media player. The source specified in the embed should be a [SWF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SWF). On the other hand there are media players built in flash (e.g. [JW FLV Media Player](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/)).
2. Flash doesn't accept WMV but uses [FLV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video) / MPEG-4.
3. The streaming protocol used is [RTMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Messaging_Protocol), not sure how to handle an ASF stream in flash.

Comment: Thanks Theo.T, flash player I mean the playe we use to play Youtube video. 1. why you mention ASF stream? Do you mean asf/wmv is using ASF stream which Flash player can not support? 2. do you have any documents claim flash player does not support wmv format?

Comment: 1. Sorry I thought that was what you had, not sure what I got that from. 2. Have a look here for the supported formats : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_Video

Comment: Thanks Theo.T, 1. I need to play asf because all present videos are of this format, so flash media player does not support it? 2. I looked through the link, seems wmv/asf file format are not listed, so not supported by Flash Media Player?

Comment: Sorry for confusing term "Flash Media Player", actually what I mean is "About Adobe Flash Player 10" -- which is shown when we right click on a Youtube video. So, for the sample of Youtube, the "About Adobe Flash Player 10" plays flv or plays swf?

Comment: Flash Player 10 reads SWFs. "Flash Media Player" is a SWF. "Flash Media Player" reads FLVs.

Comment: You should browse around Wikipedia and Google if your new to this, there's an incredible amount of information about the subject. Good luck ; )

Comment: Thanks Theo.T, so Youtube converts all videos into flv format and using "a popular SWF" Flash Media Player to render it? Correct?

Comment: 1. Looks like Flash Player also does not support Microsoft ASF format? I did not find ASF in the supported list. Correct? 2. In my sample, I think IE automatically finds ASF is rendered, so Microsoft Windows Media Player is using? IE is so smart to switch player, any comments?

Comment: (continue) even if we explicitly assign type as "application/x-shockwave-flash", IE will smartly do the player switch. Not sure whether it is IE or something else so smart! :-)

Comment: 1. Correct 2. Indeed, in IE as well as in your operating system MIME formats are associated with applications to read them.

Comment: Should we consider this question finished ? I need to get some break fast now :)

Comment: Please feel free to take your time, Theo. :-) I just have the last question, do you have any links about how Youtube is doing to convert media format (e.g. convert all media format to flv format and using mplayer)?

Comment: haha, thanks for that : ) I bet youtube has a complex internal procedure for that, don't think this is public. FFMPEG is a great software you can use both server and client side to convert various formats to FLV. http://www.google.com/search?q=ffmpeg+convert+to+flv

Comment: I know FFMPEG. I am just interested how Youtube is dealing with various input format. Are they using FFMPEG to do format conversion? I searched but can not find any documents online or blogs. Do you have any such information? I am very interested.

Comment: Hi Theo.T, I browsed it for half an hour, can not find it answers my question. But anyway, your replies are good enough. Looks like youtube is not open their encoding process.

Answer (score 1):

It's not so much that Flash doesn't support wmv/asf; it's more the fact that wmv/asf is not a Flash movie, so you can't pretend that it's one by putting it in the src attribute when you're using the application/x-shockwave-flash type. Try putting a media player Flash movie instead.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio, flash media is fine. I am just wondering 1. whether flash media player supports playing asf/wmv file format media? 2. if not supported, why I could upload wmv media to Youtube and then play it in Youtube using Flash Media Player?

Comment: Youtube lets you upload the video in a select range of formats, then converts it to .flv on the server side.

Comment: "then converts it to .flv on the server side" -- interested. Do you have any documents about this? I am interested to read more.

Comment: Nothing on what Youtube does specifically, but mplayer (http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) will convert between different video formats.

Comment: Thanks, are there any claims that youtube is using mplayer? Not find any documents or blogs mentioning that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Mediaelement.js** player documentation says, support to **wmv** and **mov**, but so far i have not seen any positive or success comments for these formats.Formats like wmv and mov are proprietary, so to play video user need to explicitly install browser based plugins. Latest version of Firefox doesn't support wmv directly, there is a work around.To support **mov** format,user need to have quicktime player install in the system.

[WMV plugin for firefox](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-in/windows/download-windows-media-player)

[Firefox Documentation:](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/play-windows-media-files-in-firefox)